# How do I iterate through a series of filenames if the previous option does not exist in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a directory of files and each filename begins with the date in the format, 'YYYYMMDD.' Given a filename, how do I check if it exists and, if it doesn't, check the filename with the subsequent date?

I have the following, but it only checks if the filename exists.

```
try:
   with open('filename') as f: pass
except IOError as e:
   print 'The file does not exist.'
```

If there is only one file in the list, I want to exit. If there are several files in the list, I want to check the following date.

Answer (score 3):

```
import glob
import bisect

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('*'))

def get_file_name_prev(fname):
    idx = bisect.bisect_right(filenames, fname)-1
    if idx < 0:
        raise ValueError('no preceding filename is available')
    else:
        return filenames[idx]

def get_file_name_next(fname):
    idx = bisect.bisect_left(filenames, fname)
    if idx >= len(filenames):
        raise ValueError('no subsequent filename is available')
    else:
        return filenames[idx]
```

**Edit:** @J.F. Sebastian: it is easy to test.

```
filenames = ['b', 'd']

get_file_name_prev('c')  # => returns 'b'
get_file_name_next('c')  # => returns 'd'
```

If he wants the **next** file name, then he needs `bisect.bisect_left`.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: (sigh) because DOS background, that's why. Will fix.

Comment: +1 for bisect. You might mean `bisect.bisect()` instead of `bisect_left()`. You need to handle IndexError

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: `bisect.bisect()` is an alias for `bisect.bisect_right()`, which is *not* what I meant.

Comment: you shouldn't substruct one from bisect_right: `bisect_left(range(4), 1)` returns `1`, `bisect_right(range(4), 1)` returns `2` i.e., the index of the next item

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: the functions do precisely what is desired: if the requested file name exists, it is returned; if it does not, the next alphabetically preceding or following filename is returned. It WORKS. Please test the actual code before complaining further.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a path is an existing file:

[`os.path.isfile(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

> Return `True` if *path* is an existing
>   regular file. This follows symbolic
>   links, so both `islink()` and
>   `isfile()` can be true for the same
>   path.

more follows....